# Check reference for NULL value C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

I have read that "Checking if a reference equals null is meaningless in C++" - because references can never have a null value. But, I see that this statement does not hold in the following example I came up with:

```
void InsertNode(struct node*& head, int data)
{
    cout << head << endl;

    node* temp = new node();
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        head = temp;
    else
    {
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
}
```

I am checking `if (head == NULL)`. Even though, head is passed as a reference, I am checking if it equals `NULL`. This contradicts with the statement that I read "Checking if a reference equals null is meaningless in C++" - Could any one please explain if my understanding is right ? Thanks.

Comment: No need for `struct` in the parameter list in C++. Separate namespaces for structures and other types only exist in C.

Comment: You are not checking the reference. You are checking the referent, which happens to be a pointer.

Comment: Testing the reference would be `if (nullptr == &head)`.

Comment: @n.m A reference is an alias to 'something' and this 'something' is called the referent right ? then this means, checking the reference and checking the referent is same right - given reference is just an alias to the referent.

Comment: @Jarod42 Doesn't "&head" return the address of the head ?

Comment: @prasha6: `head` is a alias (reference) of a variable, `&head` return the address of that variable.

Comment: @Jarod42 In that case testing for a reference to be null will be "if (nullptr == head)" and not "if (nullptr == &head)" ?

Comment: Will be clearer without pointer: with `int i = 42; int& ref = i;` checking reference for `nullptr` is `if (&ref == nullptr)` (or `if (&i == nullptr)`).

Comment: References *always* refer to an object and an object's address may not be null, @Jarod42. If you somehow break the rule to get a reference at null, you caused undefined behaviour and your program is broken anyway. A compiler could also easily elide any checks whether a reference refers to an object at null.

Answer (score 7):

You don't check if the reference is null but whether it refers to a null pointer, which is something different.

Maybe an example would help:

```
int i = 42;
// check if a variable is null
if (i == 0) print("i is null");

// pointer
int* pi = &i;
// check if a pointer is null
if (pi == 0) print("pi is null");
// check if a pointer points to a null
if (*pi == 0) print("i is null");

// reference
int& ri = i;
// check if a reference refers to a null
if (ri == 0) print("i is null");
```

There is another description of a reference that might help: A reference is a self-dereferencing, non-null pointer. That means that you never have to write `*pi` to get at the object it points to, but just `ri`. It also means that it is guaranteed to be non-null. Note that you can write programs that break this guarantee, but those programs cause so-called undefined behaviour anyway, so it's not worth bothering with it and hence the statement that initially confused you.

Comment: In that case, how would I check if the reference is null ?

Comment: You don't, because "Checking if a reference equals null is meaningless in C++". This distinction is important when comparing C++ to e.g. Java, where a reference can actually be null or when comparing C++ references to C++ pointers, which can also be null.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ulrich ! But I am still a little unclear.
What's the difference between between reference being null and what a reference refers to being null ? aren't both the same ?
Could you give me an example on how you check if a reference is null and how you check what it refers to being null ?